# Question about characteristics function of a random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

The statement is: Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable with characteristic function $\phi_X(.)$.Let $Z=N(0,1)$ be independent of $X$.For each $\sigma>0$ the random variable $X_{\alpha}=X+\sigma Z$ has a density
$f_{\alpha}$ given by,
$$f_{\alpha}(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{itx}\phi_{X}(t)e^{\frac{-\sigma^2t^2}{2}}dt$$
proof: Fix $\sigma>0$ using the independence of $X$ and $Z$ we have
$$P(X_{\sigma}{\leq\alpha})=\int_{\mathbb{R}}F_Z(\frac{\alpha-x}{\sigma})d\mu_X(x)$$
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{\alpha-x}{\sigma}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-a^2}{2}da d\mu_X(x)$$
$\begin{equation}
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{\sigma}e^\frac{-(y-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}dy d\mu_X(x)
\end{equation}$...............(1)
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{\sigma}e^\frac{-(y-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}dy d\mu_X(x)$$
Let $Y=N(0,\frac{1}{\sigma^2})$ be a random variable independent of $X$ and $Z$.Then we have $\Phi_{Y}(t)=e^\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$
using the independence of $X$ and $Y$ and the definition of characteristics function we have
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^\frac{-(x-a)^2}{2\sigma^2}d\mu_X$$$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Phi_Y(x-a)d\mu_X......(2)$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}E(e^{iXY} e^{iaY}).....(3)$$

I am having a problem with how we got (1), I think they substituted $\sigma a+x=y$ but I am confused about how this changes the integral as above. Please help.
Also how we got (3) from (2),I understood till (2) then got confused that how we got (3) from that?

Comment: One note: There is a typo in the integral before the substitution.  It should be $e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}$ instead of $e^{-\frac{a^2}{a}}$.  Outside of that, which part are you confused about?  The substitution you suggested is correct.

Comment: I am confused that after substitution with respect to what he differentiated?

Comment: A good way to think about this is that $\phi_{X + \sigma Z}(t) = \phi_X(t)\phi_{\sigma Z}(t)$, and then since $X + \sigma Z$ has a density $f_{\sigma}$ (due to regularizing property of convolution; a smooth density function convolved with a probability measure is a smooth density function), you can compute $f_{\sigma}(x)$ using the Fourier inversion formula.